# this is not defined in my function *t

Tags: javascript

The first statement which uses `this` (  line 2 ) errors with:

```
this is undefined
```

Verified the line number.  Verified that this style of use works in another function called SMessage.  Tried changing the argument name so it was not equal to the object property.  Can't figure out why it won't make the assignment to this.tag_array.  Verified tag_array1 was populated as an array of values.

```
var VBPaneInit = function ( tag_array1 ) {
    this.tag_array = tag_array1;
    this.initializeTags();
    this.initializePages();

    VBPaneInit.prototype.initializeTags = function( ) {
        var element;
        for ( element = 0; element < this.tag_array.length; element++ ) 
        {
            document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).onclick = vDomPageFlip;
        }
    };
    VBPaneInit.prototype.initializePages = function( ) {
        if ( this.tag_array.length === 0 )
        {
            return;
        }
        var index, page_element;
        for ( index = 0; index < this.tag_array.length; index++ ) 
        {  
            page_element = document.getElementById( this.tag_array[index] + '_page' );
            page_element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        vDomPageFlip( this.tag_array[0] );
    };
};
```

**The Call**

```
VBPaneInit( tag_array );
```

For testing purposes reduce to :

```
var VBPaneInit = function( tag_array ) {
    this.tag_array = tag_array;
}
```

Still no go.

Working Similar:

```
var SMessage = function ( element ) {
    this.element = element;
    SMessage.prototype.display = function( type ) {
        this.element.innerHTML = this.messages[ type ];
    };
    SMessage.prototype.messages = {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        pass:         'Please enter password, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:chris@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
        s_name:       'Please enter a valid name.',
        s_email:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        s_pass:       'Please enter password, 6-40 characters.',
        s_url:        'Please enter a valid url.',
        s_title:      'Please enter a valid title.',
        s_tweet:      'Please enter a valid tweet.',
        s_empty:      'Please complete all fields.',
        s_same:       'Please make emails equal.',
        s_taken:      'Sorry, that email is taken.',
        s_validate:   'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:chris@host.com">support</a> to reset your password.'
    };
};
```

Comment: Did you really mean `vBPaneInit.prototype` or `VBPaneInit.prototype`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `this` because you're not saying `new VBPaneInit(tag_array)`, you need the `new` to create an object.

Then, your next problem is that you're not building the prototype correctly in two different ways:

1. `vBPaneInit` is not the same as `VBPaneInit`, JavaScript is case sensitive.
2. You're trying to set up the prototype inside the constructor function so it won't be there the first time you create an object and you'll be doing it each time you create an object.

You should be doing something more like this:

```
var VBPaneInit = function(tag_array1) {
    this.tag_array = tag_array1;
    this.initializeTags();
    this.initializePages();
};
VBPaneInit.prototype.initializeTags = function() {
    var element;
    for (element = 0; element < this.tag_array.length; element++) {
        document.getElementById(this.tag_array[element]).onclick = vDomPageFlip;
    }
};
VBPaneInit.prototype.initializePages = function() {
    if (this.tag_array.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var index, page_element;
    for (index = 0; index < this.tag_array.length; index++) {
        page_element = document.getElementById(this.tag_array[index] + '_page');
        page_element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    vDomPageFlip(this.tag_array[0]);
};

new VBPaneInit(tag_array);​
```

Comment: I'm not sure why...I posted SMessage above in which I put the prototype in the function and it works fine...however I think you are correct that it would load the function into the prototype each time...it would be like defining a function in a function not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have highlighted the error, so I won't hijack that, however none has pointed out what precisely the `new` keyword does and the implications for its omission and inclusion.

So, for the sake of the OP...

In JavaScript, for functions that are not event callbacks or invoked via `apply()`, `call()` or `bind()`, or which are methods of objects, the default value of `this` inside them is either window or, in ECMA5 strict mode, `undefined`.

This changes if you invoke the function with the `new` keyword, which creates an instance of the function (since JavaScript doesn't have an exact concept of classes a la other languages, though this is a simulation). In these cases, `this`, as one would expect, points to the instance.

Comment: @utkanos—you left out functions that are called as methods of objects, where `this` will reference the object. e.g. in `myObj.myMethod()` then `this` within `myMethod` will be `myObj`.